# Tensorboard- superimpose 2 plots

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, tensorboard

In tensorboard, I would like to superimpose 2 plots on the same graph (training and validation losses of a neural network).

I can see 2 separate plots, but not one plot with 2 superimposed curves. Otherwise, I get one plot in zigzag.

How can I do?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to superimpose two plots in Tensorboard. You'll have to satisfy both of the following:

1. Create two separate `tf.train.SummaryWriter` objects such that it outputs in two folders.
2. Create two summaries (e.g. `tf.scalar_summary`) with the **same name**.

For example to plot training and validation loss:

```
# Before training
train_summary = tf.scalar_summary('Loss', train_loss)
vali_summary = tf.scalar_summary('Loss', vali_loss)
train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tmp/train'), sess.graph)
vali_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tmp/vali'), sess.graph)

# And then later
train_writer.add_summary(...)
vali_writer.add_summary(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you point tensorboard at the directory containing the tf events for both runs, you should be able to see them.  (if you have them in subdirectories, point it to the parent of both).

Comment: I can see 2 separate plots, but not one superimposed plot.Otherwise, I get one plot in zigzag. I can give pics if necessary