# Plot separate learning curves with tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

[image: myplot: accuracy]

Running a NN model with tensorflow, I want to plot the accuracy score on both training set and test set. However, the plot tensorboard showed me looked weird: there was only one 'accuracy' tab there, and it plotted the two scores on that same figure. So basically, every step on the x axis has two points connected together. How can I plot two lines (training accuracy and test accuracy) separately on that figure?

Here's a snippet of my code:

`loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
acc_summary = tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)`

`summary_loss, summary_acc_train = sess.run([loss_summary, acc_summary], feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
summary_acc_test = sess.run([acc_summary], feed_dict={X: X_test, y: y_test})`

`summary_writer.add_summary(summary_loss, epoch)
summary_writer.add_summary(summary_acc_train, epoch)
summary_writer.add_summary(summary_acc_test, epoch)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorboard- superimpose 2 plots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799850/tensorboard-superimpose-2-plots)

Comment: Are `train_loss` and `vali_loss` the same object having different names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create two different summary writers:

```
train_summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join(SUMMARIES_DIR, "train"), sess.graph)
validation_summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join(SUMMARIES_DIR, "validation"), sess.graph)

 ...

train_summary_writer.add_summary(summary_loss, epoch)
train_summary_writer.add_summary(summary_acc_train, epoch)
validation_summary_writer.add_summary(summary_acc_test, epoch)
```